# class file for com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException not found

Tags: java, json, maven, spring-mvc, jackson

My project use Spring MVC for front End and EJB for back-end. when i use jackson to serialize and deserialize  json string in controller level bellow code working properly but service layer it gives an error "**class file for com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException not found**"

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Object convertedObject = mapper.readValue(jsonString, class);
```

and my module pom file include  dependency.

```
       <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
      </dependency>
```

this error comes wth `mapper` after creating object.

Error: `Error:(247, 67) java: cannot access com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException
  class file for com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException not found`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You also need to include

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```